# Why is n always null when inserting an element in a list?

Tags: java, linked-list

For a project, I have to make a LinkedList class that connects ListNode objects that just contain the Temperature object, and a reference to the next ListNode. Those classes work well, but within the LinkedList class, I can't figure out why "n" is always null when I try to assign it to something.

LinkedList:

```
public class LinkedList {
ListNode ln = new ListNode();
private ListNode first = ln;
private ListNode last = ln;
private int length = 0;

public void append(Temperature s) {
    ListNode n = new ListNode(s);
    last.next = n;
    last = n;
    length++;
}

public void printList(TemperatureGUI gui) {
    ListNode p = first.next;
    while (p != null) {
        //gui.listAppend(Float.toString(p.data.getTemperature()) + "\n");
        System.out.println(p.data.getTemperature());
        p = p.next;
    }
}

public ListNode find(Temperature s) {
    ListNode n = first.next;
    while (n != null && !(n.data).equals(s)) {
        n = n.next;
    }
    return n;
}

public void insert(Temperature temp) {
    ListNode n = first.next;
    ListNode x = new ListNode(temp);

    // if it's the first element in the linked list,
    // make the parameter the first in the list
    if (n == null) {
        n = x;
        length++;
        System.out.println(length);
        return;
    }

    while (n != null &&
           n.next != null &&
           n.data.compareTo(temp) == -1) { // -1 means data is less than temp
        if (n.next.data.compareTo(temp) == 1) { // 1 means data is greater than temp
            break;
        }
        n = n.next;
    }

    // if it's the last element on the list, append it to the end
    if (n.equals(last) && n.next == null) {
        n.next = x;
        last = x;
        length++;
        return;
    }

    x.next = n.next;
    n.next = x;
    length++;
}
```

}

The problem lies here:

```
if (n == null) {
        n = x;
        length++;
        System.out.println(length);
        return;
    }
```

where it always prints the length, and nothing else runs. Why is n always null here even with an assignment to it?

Comment: How do you initialize the list?

Comment: I suggest stepping through the code very carefully, using paper and pencil, especially the case where you create a list and do the first insert.

Comment: I only initialized it with a blank constructor, as it should be ready to go with `new LinkedList();`

Comment: What does `ListNode` look like?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
ListNode n = first.next; //n is a reference to first.next
n = x; // n is no longer a reference to first.next
```

n is a local variable for the method. So whatever you do to n, it does not affect to the first and last global references.

So every time whenver you call the method, n is null because first.next is always null. So do the assignment as

```
first.next = x; // instead of n = x;
```

Comment: `first` and `last` share a reference, which is also a problem.

Comment: ohhh OP is expecting **n** to be a reference to **first.next** I get it now.

Comment: I forgot all about scope during this, but it is running a bit more expectedly now. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

When you say

```
 ListNode n = first.next;
```

You are declaring a new variable and instantiating it with a reference to the same object as first.next. This code here:

```
if (n == null) {
    n = x;
    length++;
    System.out.println(length);
}
```

Will change the reference contained in the variable n but note that first.next has not been modified. This is because the line

```
ListNode n = first.next;
```

Does not provide n a reference to the variable first.next, but rather copies the value of first.next into n.

Edit: To actually fix the problem, you will need to change

```
n = x;
```

to

```
first.next = x;
```

While it is not essential to your code, I would also recommend using first.next instead of n throughout your code. 'n' is not a terribly descriptive variable name while first.next is much more readable. It will help your teacher and your classmates understand your code and will not make your program any less efficient.